# How to make a function return the result in console?

Tags: javascript

```js
let numbers = [1,5,22];
let doubledNumbers = numbers.map(n => n*2);
    
function doubledNumbersFn() {
    return numbers.map(n => n*2)
}
    
doubledNumbersFn();
```

When I run these codes at

[image]

I see the result on the right, but when I ran it on JSfiddle I don't see anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to run `console.log(doubledNumbersFn())` in order for it to be published to console.